# Can we add a confirm message when posting on old stale posts

Tags: feature-request

Every once in a while an old question or answer will show up in the review queue or at the top of the active questions list.  This often has the result of additional flags and comments being posted as new people see the post.

Some of the time this is not terribly constructive.

If there was a confirm before posting a comment, flag, or answer on a question or answer that has not had activity for 30 days that might help avoid some of this activity.  I don't think this is likely to be a great hindrance to quality posts and it may help avoid reigniting discussions and comment wars that had calmed down.  And help keep me from making my self look like a fool when i comment on a year old post because someone flagged it.

Comment: If there is a good reason to flag or comment on a post, you should do it - be it five minutes old or five years old.

Comment: @Thursday - The problem is many comments are not really good reasons in the first place. The idea here is the confirm wont stop the good ones but it will hopefully stop some of the not so good ones.  And if the mods havent seen the need to deal with a post after 30 days again a confirm message is not going to stop the reasonable ones, butmight stop some of the less appropriate revenge flags.

Comment: I see that you're asking this as you made a few mistakes yourself, and you're also requesting this for flags. But *just in case* you also think it would keep folks from posting a non-answer to old posts: you know that new users get to see [a warning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nFThK.png) for all their first answers? I guess we don't know how many are stopped there, but surely many ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are not proposing that a question and answer site discourage answers on posts because they might be old. But that's what it looks like.

If we want to discourage answers on questions, then we close the questions. Closing questions has always been based on question quality and appropriateness of the topic to the site. If the question is on-topic I see no reason to hinder answers for it.

If we want to discourage comments on posts, we flag the ones out of place. I don't see why the date of a comment should effect the decision to flag or reply to it.

Examples:

- I [commented](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/is-the-earth-6000-years-old/1441#comment54919_1441) on [a post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/is-the-earth-6000-years-old/1441) nearly two years later and  received [a reply](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/is-the-earth-6000-years-old/1441#comment74098_1441) nearly a year after that. I don't think we should stop that because it might generate a few flags (and this was certain one of those posts that has generated flags).
- [I answered](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/how-long-can-a-naked-human-survive-on-mars/14423#14423) a [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/8272/3970) eight months later, stole the selection and [earned the necromancer badge.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=3970) Answering late is encouraged behavior, assuming you are answering genuinely and think you can provide something that the other answers didn't already supply.

But would having a little "are you sure" alert message even work? I don't think so. If I am answering genuinely, I'm going to click "yes." If not, I'm probably still going to click "yes" because I don't care; I not being honest with the community in the first place.

On posts prone to flags, that's just going to happen and the only way to stop it would be to lock or delete those posts, because even closing them doesn't stop comments.

Comment: This would not stop it though.  This would just give the poster a chance to say hey do you really want to post a comment on an old answer.  If they do then so be it.  The intention is not to stop good posts its to let people know that they are about to comment on an old post.  Its not a big deal on SO or other sites that are less likely to see discussions break out but on sites like the workplace old posts can wake up into new comment arguments and piled on bad flags.

Comment: @Chad Extended comments are already discouraged with the move to chat message. I can't speak for everyone, but I certainly wouldn't care the post was old or not, and I have a feeling most users would notice before deciding to comment anyway. I just don't see this as helping accomplish anything, and what you want it to accomplish is something we have to put up with anyway: people will argue one way or the other. I participate heavily on Christianity.SE, so I've seen my share of it.